# Android: Change the background drawable of first and last items in a listview?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a custom adapter which extends BaseAdapter. On the getView() method when I use the "position/index" to check if it is the first and last item, the listview items don't render the proper background drawable for each item as it's a recyclable list. As a result, on scroll of the listview, the items obtain the same drawable background as given for index == 0.

```
@override
void getView(int index, View convertview, Viewgroup parent) {
    if(index == 0) {
        row.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable, null, null, null);
    } else {
        row.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable2, null, null, null);
    }
}
```

How do I effectively and efficiently achieve this different drawable resources for them?

**EDIT:**
Added adapter code below:

```
public class iAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private String[] data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    private TextView listItem;

    public iAdapter(Activity a, String[] d) {
        activity = a;
        data = d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

@Override
public View getView(int index, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = convertView;
    if(convertView==null) {
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null);
    }
    if(index == 0) {
        rowView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_header_image, null, null, null);
    } else if(index == data.length-1) {
        rowView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_header_image2, null, null, null);
    }

    listItem = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.custom_text);
    listItem.setText(data[index]);
    return rowView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
}
```

Comment: Your entire Adapter class please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write else condition to set drawable for other indexes rather than firat and last index:

```
if(index == 0) {
rowView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds
       (activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_header_image,
                                null,  null, null);
} else if(index == data.length-1) {
    rowView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds
      (activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_header_image2, 
      null, null, null);
}else  {
    rowView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds
      (activity.getResources().getDrawable(other_drawable_id, 
      null, null, null);
}
```

Comment: Oops, my code without else was the mistake. Thanks. works now!

Answer (score 0):

Try in this manner

```
    @override 
private void getView(int index, View convertview, Viewgroup parent) { 
if(index == 0){ 
row.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
 }else if(index == get count()-1) { 
row.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable1);
 }else{ 
row.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable2); 
} }
```

Answer (score 0):

try to this code, i hope solution you have,

i think, its position issues so this code you should try.

```
    if(index == 0) {
        rowView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_header_image, null, null, null));
    } else if((index+1) == data.length) {
        rowView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_header_image2, null, null, null));
    } else { 
        rowView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(activity.getResources().getDrawable(other_drawable_id, null, null, null));
    }
```